# Flutter error: unable to find utility "xcodebuild", not a developer tool or in PATH

Tags: xcode, flutter, macos, dart, arm64

I get the following error message when I reinstalled Flutter and Xcode and want to launch a newly created Flutter application for macOS Desktop.

```
   Launching lib/main.dart on macOS in debug mode...
    lib/main.dart:1
    ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
    xcrun: error: unable to find utility "xcodebuild", not a developer tool or in PATH
      Command: /usr/bin/arch -arm64e xcrun xcodebuild -list -project Runner.xcodeproj
    Exited
```

Comment: You need to point xcode-select at the new copy of Xcode.

Answer (score 6):

Many thanks to Matt,

**Solution**

Open Xcode and choose a version to point

Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> Command Line Tools -> XX.XX